# libgit2 (fetch & merge & commit)

Tags: libgit2

I 'm trying to pull from a repo with libgit2.

My steps are these:

- git_remote_connect - OK
- git_remote_download or should I use git_remote_fetch ?
- git_remote_ls to get the of the HEAD to pass to git_annotated_commit_from_fetchhead (is this coorect?). But there are more than 1 heads, do I pass the one with "HEAD" name?
- git_merge.

This results in MERGE_HEAD in .git folder and then I am able to merge with an existing commit.

The question is, is the above sequence correct? Why git creates FETCH_HEAD whereas libgit2 has MERGE_HEAD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to use `git_remote_fetch`, not `git_remote_download`.  `fetch` is a convenience function that performs the download *and* updates things like the remote tracking branches to point to the data that is on the server and - more importantly for you - the `FETCH_HEAD` file.

You can determine which branch to feed to `git_merge` by examining the `FETCH_HEAD` lines and identifying the branch that is *not* marked as `not-for-merge`.  The simplest way to do this is to iterate over them using `git_repository_fetchhead_foreach`.  Your callback will be invoked for each line, and you simply need to make note of the one that has `for_merge` set to `true`.  The branch marked as `for-merge` will be the remote branch corresponding to the `merge` line in your config.

That is to say that if your `HEAD` points to `master`, and your configuration is:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Then when you fetched from `origin`, the corresponding remote `master` branch would be marked as `for-merge`.  Once you have identified this `FETCH_HEAD` entry, then you can create an annotated commit from it and call `git_merge`.

Note that both git core and libgit2 will create `FETCH_HEAD`s when fetching and `MERGE_HEAD`s when merging.  You will only see the latter when the merge is ongoing - so if you run `merge --no-commit` on the command-line or if you have a conflict.  You can use this to compare the data that git core produces to ensure that you are producing the same data using libgit2.

Comment: Hi, how can I setup the callback for git_repository_fetchhead_foreach?